# Set Number of Threads for Armadillo

Tags: armadillo, openblas

How can I make Armadillo use OpenBLAS with OpenMP?  I installed OpenBLAS with Homebrew with the --with-openmp option, and I'm building my application with: `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.3.0_1/bin/g++-6 -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -fopenmp -L/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/7.600.2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2_2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.2.18_2/lib/ -larmadillo -lopenblas -llapack -lnlopt -I/usr/local/include -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/file1.d" -MT"src/file2.o" -o "src/file3.o" "../src/file4.cpp"`.  However, setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` doesn't change the number of threads the program actually uses.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm on OSX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you would use
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1